# How can I merge these two objects in javascript in an elegent way (Preferably using lodash)?

Tags: javascript, merge, lodash

```
var object = {
  'a': {'b' : {'f' :5}, 'c' : {'e' : 6}},
  'd' : {'m' : {'n' : 10}}
};
 
var other = {
  'b': {"red" : 4},
  'c': {"red" : 10},
  'm': {"red" :5}
};
```

The final object should look like :

```
var mergedObject = {
  'a': {'b' : {'f' :5 , 'red' : 4}, 'c' : {'e' : 6, 'red' : 10}},
  'd' : {'m' : {'n' : 10, 'red' : 5}}
};
```

I tried using the merge functions in lodash's merge functions but that didn't work as I think the structure of the two objects differ.

Answer (score 1):

Provided all values are serializable, you can use `JSON.stringify` with a "merger" callback:

```js
var object = {
    'a': {'b' : {'f' :5}, 'c' : {'e' : 6}},
    'd' : {'m' : {'n' : 10}}
};

var other = {
    'b': {"red" : 4},
    'c': {"red" : 10},
    'm': {"red" :5}
};


res = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(object, (key, val) => {
        if (key in other)
            return {...val, ...other[key]}
        return val
    })
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an approach by getting entries with added properties and rebuild the objects.

```js
const
    merge = (object, values) => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([k, v]) => [
            k,
            v && typeof v === 'object'
                ? { ...merge(v, values), ...values[k] }
                : v
        ])
    ),
    object = { a: { b: { f: 5 }, c: { e: 6 } }, d: { m: { n: 10 } } },
    other = { b: { red: 4 }, c: { red: 10 }, m: { red: 5 } },
    merged = merge(object, other);
    
console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.assign` method

```js
var object = {
    a: { b: { f: 5 }, c: { e: 6 } },
    d: { m: { n: 10 } },
};

var otherObj = {
    b: { red: 4 },
    c: { red: 10 },
    m: { red: 5 },
};

function merge(target) {
    for (const key in target) {
        if (otherObj[key]) Object.assign(target[key], otherObj[key]);
        else merge(target[key]);
    }
}
merge(object);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve this in Lodash.

You will need reduce each value by merging each sub item with its lookup value.

```js
const object = {
  'a' : { 'b' : { 'f' :  5 }, 'c' : { 'e' : 6 } },
  'd' : { 'm' : { 'n' : 10 } }
};
 
const other = {
  'b' : { 'red' :  4 },
  'c' : { 'red' : 10 },
  'm' : { 'red' :  5 }
};

const mergedObject = _.reduce(object, (result, value, key) =>
  _.merge(result, {
    [key]: _.reduce(value, (acc, v, k) =>
      _.merge(acc, {
        [k]: _.merge({}, v, other[k])
      }), {})
  }), {});

console.log(mergedObject); // Merged
console.log(object);       // Unmodified
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```